# post message to web service

Tags: ios, web-services, http-post

Good day!
I have a problem to post register message to web service. I have never been worked with wsdl in ios and so there is a code

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://monah-service.azurewebsites.net/soap"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"Register"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-type" value:@"xmlns:tns=""http://tempuri.org/"];
//    [request setPostValue:@"Register" forKey:@"name"];
    [request setPostValue:[loginTextField text] forKey:@"email"];

    [request buildPostBody];
//    [request buildRequestHeaders];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

web service post me an error 415 that means content type error. 
Is there any solutions?

Comment: how can i post message body? i did this on this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service

Comment: download that sample code and check whether it working

Comment: i have had tried it already. there is something else

Answer (score 0):

I think a mistake was made there

```
value:@"xmlns:tns=""http://tempuri.org/"
                  ^^
```

Comment: What are you writing in your request ? I believe `@"tempuri.org/"` may not be right. Try with `@"text/plain"` for exemple ?

Comment: Can you please show what's in your request's body ? Or the code from your **buildPostBody** method ?

Comment: that is the problem - i don't have equest's body i thought it will be automatically created. how can i write the body?